# Can I use Woocommerce to take orders but not handle payment?

Tags: e-commerce, woocommerce-offtopic

I would like to create an ecommerce website.

In this website the customer will browse the product catalog, add the desired products to his cart, maybe create an account, and during the checkout phase, will leave a phone number along with his shipping information and address.

I will then manually review every order made (and be notified via email for new orders), call the person and handle it from then on.

Is this possible or do I have to let woocommerce handle the payments using a gateway like PayPal?

If it is possible, can someone please guide me how to set it up like so?

Comment: This question does not appear to be about WordPress within the scope defined in the help center, as plugin questions are generally off-topic, esp. questions about issues with and modifying plugins. Refer to the plugin author or company.  See http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use multiple payment gateways. Simply use one of the default payment gateways that doesn't require immediately payment and you can rename it in the settings, so you have the same process that you described above. For example the "Cash on Delivery" gateway is ideal, you can edit the title and the description of the method in woocommerce settings.

Comment: Great, cash on delivery is exactly what we're doing!